# ucrtbased.dll: Access Violation

Tags: c++, runtime

I am writing an extension (that is compiled as dynamic library), and I get extension error. Unfortunately, I have to draw entire GUI by myself, unfortunately, in pretty raw GDI/WinAPI.
This is my code that crashes:

```
    Slider::Slider(const char* objectId, int height, POINT topLeft, int visibleElements, int totalElements, int elementHeight, EuroScopePlugIn::CRadarScreen* rs)
    {
        // Member variable initailization
        m_ObjectId = objectId;
        m_Height = height;
        m_TopLeft = topLeft;
        m_VisibleElements = visibleElements;
        m_ElementHeight = elementHeight;
        m_TotalElements = totalElements;
        m_Width = 10;
        m_pRS = rs;
        m_CurrentFirstElement = 0;
        m_CurrentLastElement = m_CurrentFirstElement + visibleElements;
    }

    SliderGrip::SliderGrip(Slider* sliderObject) : Slider(m_ObjectId.c_str(), m_Height, m_TopLeft, m_VisibleElements, m_TotalElements, m_ElementHeight, m_pRS)
    {
        // Base class member variable initialization
        {
            m_ObjectId = sliderObject->m_ObjectId;
            m_Height = sliderObject->m_Height;
            m_TopLeft = sliderObject->m_TopLeft;
            m_VisibleElements = sliderObject->m_VisibleElements;
            m_ElementHeight = sliderObject->m_ElementHeight;
            m_TotalElements = sliderObject->m_TotalElements;
            m_Width = sliderObject->m_Width;
            m_pRS = sliderObject->m_pRS;
            m_CurrentFirstElement = sliderObject->m_CurrentFirstElement;
            m_CurrentLastElement = sliderObject->m_CurrentLastElement;
        }
        m_GripHeight = (m_VisibleElements / m_TotalElements) * m_ElementHeight;
        m_GripTopLeft = (CPoint)(m_TopLeft.x, m_TopLeft.y + 10 + (m_CurrentFirstElement * m_ElementHeight));
    }

    void SliderGrip::RenderGrip(CDC* dc)
    {
        // localObjectId
        std::string localObjectId = "Grip";
        // Save DC for later
        int sDC = dc->SaveDC();

        // Create CRectangle
        CRect CRectangle(m_GripTopLeft.x, m_GripTopLeft.y, m_GripTopLeft.x + m_Width, m_GripTopLeft.y + m_GripHeight);

        // Grip Color
        COLORREF m_GripColor = RGB(0, 0, 0);

        // Fill CRectangle with CBrush
        CBrush RectangleFill(m_GripColor);
        dc->FillRect(&CRectangle, &RectangleFill);

        
        m_pRS->AddScreenObject(CELEMENTS::SCROLLBAR_GRIP, localObjectId.c_str(), CRectangle, 1, "");
        // Restore DC
        dc->RestoreDC(sDC);
        
        // Cleaning
        DeleteObject(RectangleFill);
    }

    SliderTrack::SliderTrack(Slider* sliderObject) : Slider(m_ObjectId.c_str(), m_Height, m_TopLeft, m_VisibleElements, m_TotalElements, m_ElementHeight, m_pRS)
    {
        // Base class member variable initialization
        {
            m_ObjectId = sliderObject->m_ObjectId;
            m_Height = sliderObject->m_Height;
            m_TopLeft = sliderObject->m_TopLeft;
            m_VisibleElements = sliderObject->m_VisibleElements;
            m_ElementHeight = sliderObject->m_ElementHeight;
            m_TotalElements = sliderObject->m_TotalElements;
            m_Width = sliderObject->m_Width;
            m_pRS = sliderObject->m_pRS;
            m_CurrentFirstElement = sliderObject->m_CurrentFirstElement;
            m_CurrentLastElement = sliderObject->m_CurrentLastElement;
        }

        m_TrackHeight = m_VisibleElements * m_ElementHeight;
        m_TrackTopLeft = (CPoint)(m_TopLeft.x, m_TopLeft.y + 10);
    }

    void SliderTrack::RenderTrack(CDC* dc)
    {
        // Save DC for later
        int sDC = dc->SaveDC();

        // CRectangle
        CRect CRectangle(m_TrackTopLeft.x, m_TrackTopLeft.y, m_TrackTopLeft.x + m_Width, m_TrackTopLeft.y + m_TrackHeight);

        // Color
        COLORREF m_TrackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200);

        // Fill CRectangle with CBrush
        CBrush RectangleFill(m_TrackColor);
        dc->FillRect(&CRectangle, &RectangleFill);

        // Restore DC
        dc->RestoreDC(sDC);

        // Cleaning
        DeleteObject(RectangleFill);
    }

    SliderButton::SliderButton() : Slider(m_ObjectId.c_str(), m_Height, m_TopLeft, m_VisibleElements, m_TotalElements, m_ElementHeight, m_pRS)
    {

    }
```

[...]

```
#pragma region Scrollbar
    // Scrollbar -> Elements::Slider --- grip, track, buttonup, buttondown
    Scrollbar::Scrollbar(const char* name, EuroScopePlugIn::CRadarScreen* rs, POINT topLeft, int height, int visibleElements, int totalElements, int elementHeight)
    {
        // member Var initialization 
        m_Name = name;
        m_pRS = rs;
        m_TopLeft = topLeft;
        m_Height = height;
        m_Width = 10;
        m_VisibleElements = visibleElements;
        m_TotalElements = totalElements;
        m_ElementHeight = elementHeight;

        // initialize objects
        sliderObject = new CInterface::Slider(m_Name.c_str(), m_Height, m_TopLeft, m_VisibleElements, m_TotalElements, m_ElementHeight, m_pRS);
        gripObject = new CInterface::SliderGrip(sliderObject);
        trackObject = new CInterface::SliderTrack(sliderObject);
    }

    void Scrollbar::AddTotalElements()
    {
        m_TotalElements++;
    }
    void Scrollbar::AddTotalElements(int count)
    {
        m_TotalElements += count;
    }
    void Scrollbar::RemoveTotalElements()
    {
        if(m_TotalElements>0)
            m_TotalElements--;
    }
    void Scrollbar::RemoveTotalElements(int Count)
    {
        if (m_TotalElements > Count)
            m_TotalElements -= Count;
    }

    void Scrollbar::Render(CDC* dc)
    {
        // for later
        int sDC = dc->SaveDC();
        
        gripObject->RenderGrip(dc);
        trackObject->RenderTrack(dc);

        // restore
        dc->RestoreDC(sDC);
    }

    Scrollbar::~Scrollbar()
    {
        delete sliderObject;
        delete gripObject;
        delete trackObject;
    }

#pragma endregion Scrollbar
```

Later on, code is called from main app in this way:

```
CallingFunction()
{
 testScroll = new CInterface::Scrollbar("testScroll", this, xyz, 50, 10, 50, 5);
}
~CallingFunction()
{
 delete testScroll;
}
```

Until now, code doesn't crash, but once I call rendering functions:

```
OnRender(HDC hDC)
{
 CDC    dc;
 dc.Attach(hDC);
 testScroll->Render(&dc);
 dc.Detach();
 dc.DeleteDC();
}
```

App crashes on startup with given code error:

> Exception thrown at 0x78F6FF5C (ucrtbased.dll) in EuroScope.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.

I have no clue what's causing this, any ideas? I am roughly sure it may be issue with some pointer and/or passed `const char*`. While I tried to replace `const char*` to `std::string` whenever possible, I got an similar error, but related to `vcruntime140.dll`...

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` means uninitialized heap memory. You likely have a pointer you did not initialize.  Use your debugger to figure out which pointer. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: Where does the debugger tell you the exception is occurring? You may need to walk up the call stack to get out of the library and in to your code.

Comment: On Visual Studio Community there is a "Stack Frame" combobox on the debug toolbar that allows you to switch the call stack like the previous comment mentioned.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm unfortunately, callstack is not giving me any advice. This is what I get once OnRender is [called](https://ibb.co/Z2mCWLG)

Comment: It looks like you need to configure Visual Studio to download .pdb files from the Microsoft symbol servers.  You can configure this in Menu -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols.

Comment: @PaulSanders you're right, I've just done it. https://ibb.co/jg46XVv

Comment: No keep going down the items in that list till you find your code and inspect which of your variables is `0xCDCDCDCD`